# Preload data from xml, table view doesn't reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parsing, swift2

I have following problem. In my app I'm downloading .xml file from server and then parsing it. I call both methods (get and parse) from application:willFinnishLaunchingWithOptions.

Right after parsing is posted notification. In main table view controller is observer and selector is supposed to reload table view. But it doesn't. ViewDidLoad in TVC is called before parsing is completed, also before launching screen disappears.

So my question is: Is possible to freeze application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption till all data are parsed? Thanks

Comment: Posting some relevant code might help readers of your question gain more context and, hopefully, provide an answer. Therefore, how about posting relevant code snippets in your post?

Comment: he asked if its possible to freeze the function `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOption` So what for code do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible. What you could do:
Don't show your TVC. Show a loading Controller. This Controller will do the work with loading the data and parsing it. When its done you can call your TVC

For Example:

1. LoadingController has a instance of a Manager Class
2. The Manager downloads your file. ( Extra Communicator or something else)
3. Your provide success and failure blocks to the manager calls. Means, build a function with `func downloadXML(success: blockStuff, failure: blockstuff)`. In the success your provide the parsing
4. When parsing is finished you show your TBV with the data

Feel free to ask or comment :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I searched documentation and web for LoadingController, eventually Manager Class because I've never heard about it, but I cant find anything. Can you tell me little bit more?

Comment: your funny :) with a loadincontroller i mean a uiViewController that displays something that is indicating a loading and in loads the data from a manager that you create by your own. Just as an Model to seperate code and have a clear structure. So nothing special.

Comment: Hahah right! I was thinking about classic VC but I wasn't sure. I'm new in iOS development so sometimes I'm silly. Thanks :D

Comment: No problem :) Have fun and a nice day ;)